# List Every 6 Months Between Dates

Tags: kdb

I have a function that can list dates between a start and end date using `til

I’m trying to find something (maybe using `xbar) which will list every date in 6 month intervals from the start date

Eg. 2021.02.15 2021.07.15 2022.02.15, etc.

I have Q.addmonths[] integrated but can’t seem to put it all together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this work for you?

```
q){(-1+`dd$x)+`date$(`month$x)+y*til z}[2021.02.15;6;4]
2021.02.15 2021.08.15 2022.02.15 2022.08.15
```

It generates the number of months specified by the `z` parameter in intervals given by the `y` parameter. `x` is  your starting date.

```
`month$x - pulls out the month of your date
`dd$x - pulls out the day of the month
```

You can also use `.Q.addmonths` like you mentioned, (same parameters):

```
q){.Q.addmonths[x;y*til z]}[2021.02.15;6;4]
2021.02.15 2021.08.15 2022.02.15 2022.08.15
```

For both solutions, bear in mind the warning from the documents at https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#addmonths:

```
If the date x is near the end of the month and (x.month + y)’s month has fewer days than x.month, the result may spill over to the following month.
```

Comment: Bingo! I can proably get the rest of the way there. Rather than "z" being a literal, I'll try to rework `z to be the number of 6 month periods between x and y so this can terminate at any end date

Answer (score 1):

This approach will keep adding 6 months until it hits the end date

```
q){(-1_(y>).Q.addmonths[;6]\x),y}[2021.02.15;2022.02.15]
2021.02.15 2021.08.15 2022.02.15
```